# How to use Samsung Air View inside a Service

Tags: android, air

I can successfully use the Air View inside my Activity using the following code, but it doesn't work inside my Service that has View.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Note: When my Activity is in foreground my Service views reacts to the Air View event even after I removed the Intent-Filter from the Service.